# Can Microsoft Private Cloud provide Web/Worker roles?

Tags: azure, cloud

Microsoft Azure cloud supports three roles Web, Worker and VM with different capabilities to be utilized by application developers.

If I understand correctly when we use Web or Worker role, Azure acts more like PaaS while using VM role puts Azure in IaaS role.

Web, Worker roles has the advantage of OS/Platform being managed by the Fabric Controller (updates to OS etc), where with VM we have to manage those ourselves.

My question is, if we implement a private cloud using solutions provided by Microsoft, Can we still create Web/Worker roles on our private cloud, or is it limited to VM roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Services, which you're describing, are comprised of Web / Worker / VM roles, with Web and Worker OS's maintained by Microsoft and VM Role maintained by you (with multiple instances all based off the baseline image you upload). In all three cases, any type of new image creation is like starting fresh: changes made to the OS while running are not permanently persisted. VM Role does **not** put Windows Azure into IaaS mode, as the fabric is still using a single baseline image to manage role instances. IaaS, with **Virtual Machines**, is a bit different, with the Virtual Machines constructable in the cloud (vs. VM Role that requires them to be built locally and then uploaded). Further, any change to a Virtual Machine is persistent. When scaling to multiple instances, you'd need to make VHD copies from your master image, and then each instance would be living on its own (e.g. a change to one Virtual Machine will not show up in the other Virtual Machines).

Having said all that: You have access to Cloud Services (web/worker/vm role) only in Windows Azure today; there's no way to run these locally.

Recently we announced the availability of [Windows Azure services for Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/en/us/services.aspx). You'll see that there is a subset of Windows Azure features runnable on Windows Server:

- Web Sites
- Virtual Machines
- Service Management Portal and API

Comment: That indeed is a good explanation Sir! I'll go through the link you provided, but could you please explain if we can get features like 'fault domains' and 'upgrade domains' with Azure Services to Windows Server?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not yet.  WebRole and WorkerRole PAAS are relying on Azure Fabric Controller and that thing does not yet run on premise outside of Microsoft's control, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Yea as far as I'm aware you can, I haven't tried it myself, you need to create a VNET and then create your Cloud Services within your VNET, Michael Washam has a good post detailing it: [Connecting Web or Worker Roles to a Simple Virtual Network in Windows Azure](http://michaelwasham.com/2012/08/06/connecting-web-or-worker-roles-to-a-simple-virtual-network-in-windows-azure/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid that post does not answer my question, those web/worker roles Michael speaks of still seem to live on Public cloud (or at least it doesn't say otherwise), I want to know if we can create web/worker roles in a private cloud in the same way they are available in Azure.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question, didn't realize it was private cloud, my bad!